# trying to return 2 arrays with mongo aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wont to return a list of the words used and a list of the overall scores.

I have in my doc like this

```
   "negativeWords" : [
        "Angry"
    ],
    "positiveWords" : [
        "Happy"
    ],
```

each doc can have multiple negative or positive words.

also Each doc has overall score like:

```
"overall" : 3,
```

I want to get array like :

```
words : [Angry, Happy, Sad, bad, excited]
```

and overall score array for each doc:

overall : [4,3,2,5,]

I don't know how to get both.

```
Review.aggregate([


//now I want to get the overall scores and the array of words
{
    $project: {
        arr : {"$setUnion" : ["$negativeWords", "$positiveWords"]},
        overallScores : "$overall"
    }
},
{
    $unwind : "$arr"
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        words : {$push : "$arr"},
        overallScores : {$first : "$overallScores"}
    }
},
```

EDIT:
now I'm up to here in output. I want to get the arrays:

```
[ { _id: 5898b02c1321831b84740320,
    words: [ 'Angry', 'Happy' ],
    overallScores: 3 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031f,
    words:
     [ 'Difficult',
       'Easy returns',
       'Afordable',
       'Great products',
       'Good service' ],
    overallScores: 5 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031e,
    words:
     [ 'Difficult',
       'Easy returns',
       'Afordable',
       'Great products',
       'Good service' ],
    overallScores: 5 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031d,
    words: [ 'Caring', 'Easy returns', 'Bad', 'Expensive' ],
    overallScores: 3 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031c,
    words: [ 'Difficult', 'Afordable', 'Awesome' ],
    overallScores: 4 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031b,
    words: [ 'Bad', 'Respect', 'Rude', 'Expensive', 'Disgusted' ],
    overallScores: 3 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b8474031a,
    words: [ 'Difficult', 'Afordable' ],
    overallScores: 4 },
  { _id: 5898b02c1321831b84740319,
    words: [ 'No refund', 'Respect' ],
    overallScores: 3 } ]
```

the code:

```
{
    $project: {
        arr : {"$setUnion" : ["$negativeWords", "$positiveWords"]},
        overallScores : "$overall"
    }
},
{
    $unwind : "$arr"
},
{$unwind : "$overallScores"},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        words : {$push : "$arr"},
        overallScores : {$first : "$overallScores"}
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the overall field relate to the arrays, or don't they?

Comment: overall is just a number. They don't relate to the positiveWords  and negativeWords array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without having to worry about using `$unwind`:

```
$group : {
    _id: null,
    words: {
        $addToSet: {
            $setUnion: ["$negativeWords", "$positiveWords"]
        },
    },
    overallScores: {
        $push: "$overall"
    },
}

$project : {
    _id: 0,
    overallScores: 1,
    words: {
        $reduce: {
            input: '$words',
            initialValue: [],
            in : {
                $setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this']
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but `$reduce` is for version 3.4 . I have 3.2 .